# Jquery dropdown box's first item disabled is selected on page load

Tags: jquery, combobox, drop-down-menu, dropbox

I have a dropbox on my page from where a user can choose an item. From there they can choose to click on a button wich appends another dropbox (with jquery clone). What happends next is that the first dropbox gets disabled and the selected option from this first box is hidden in my second dropbox. This all works, but there's one problem: when I choose the first option in the first box, this option is the selected one in my second box. When I open the box, it's not there, so I can't select it myself, but it is automaticly selected when I add the box!

Briefly
- two dropdowns
- selected option in dropdown 1 gets hidden in dropdown 2
- selected first option from dropdown 1 != selected (hidden) option in dropdown 2

I already tried disabling the option and refreshing the box but the option keeps being selected on the page load.

This is how I hide the item:
`$('.group option[value='+selitem+']').hide();`

Any ideas?

Comment: Since your example is somewhat complex, I would suggest putting together a jsFiddle that shows the errant behavior so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: fiddle link if you need it http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try would be to de-select the option like this:

```
.attr("selected","");
```

I've recently been struggling with select boxes, and I've found that there is not enough cross-browser consistency in how they behave regarding what they show as "selected" if nothing is selected, especially when adding and removing elements from them.

One solution to this that others have suggested (and I considered but my requirements didn't make it worth my time) is to replace the select box with a more flexible jQuery-based solution that either replaces the browser's select box with a "custom" one that mimics it, or to use a different UI from a select box and make it out of a list (possibly out of a list of radio buttons as the backing elements)

Comment: Well, thank you for the quick reponse. It's a little better. Now the selected field is just empty. But it's not how it should be. I guess the only option is to make it select any other item. Is there a way to do this without a loop?

Comment: @Jovy - You could try putting a default "Please select" sort of option as the first option of the new select box. You would be able to de-select the incoming option and set the default to be selected. That wouldn't require a loop, but when I've done this, I have still run into different behavior across browsers (see my updated answer above)

Comment: That's a better workaround than I have now, thanks. I had set the selected option to .next() and that helped too. But yours is better :)